# How to find all unique filenames (eliminate duplicates and paths)

Tags: linux, shell, find, sh

How do I find all unique filenames, eliminate duplicate names, and eliminate directory names?

e.g., given these directories/folders and files:

```
dir-aa/file-1
dir-aa/subdir-cc/file-2
dir-bb/file-1
dir-bb/file-3
```

I want this output:

```
file-1
file-2
file-3
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort -u
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f -exec basename '{}' ';' | sort -u
```

Comment: Well done.  For a slightly simpler & faster approach, try: `find . -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort -u`.

Comment: Nice, thanks @John1024!  I've now added your approach as well.